# valueStateText not defined for SAPUI5 custom control

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have below custom control created by extending sap.m.Input that lets the user enter only numbers. However, when there is actually an error the state of control changes to Error with red borders but the valueStateText is not displayed when it has focus. How can I get the valueStateText for my custom control? Shouldn't it inherit from sap.m.Input?

Custom Control code:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/Input"
], function (Control) {
    "use strict";
    return Control.extend("sample.control.NumericInput", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {},
            aggregations: {},
            events: {}
        },
        init: function () {
            if (sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onInit) {
                sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onInit.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            this.attachLiveChange(this.onLiveChange);
        },
        renderer: function (oRM, oControl) {
            sap.m.InputRenderer.render(oRM, oControl);
        },
        onLiveChange: function (e) {
            var _oInput = e.getSource();
            var val = _oInput.getValue();
            val = val.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
            _oInput.setValue(val);
        }
    });
});
```

XML code:

```
<hd:NumericInput value="{path:'payload>/MyNumber',type:'sap.ui.model.type.String',constraints:{minLength:1,maxLength:10}}" valueStateText="My Number must not be empty. Maximum 10 characters."/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `init` override you need to call the `init` of the parent control (not onInit of `sap.ui.core.Control`). The `init` of the `sap.m.InputBase` (`sap.m.Input`'s parent class) sets up the valuestate initial values and rendering so it's missing all that code out and not working correctly as you've found.

Check out this example based on your code:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/Input"
], function (Control) {
    "use strict";
  
    return Control.extend("sample.control.NumericInput", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {},
            aggregations: {},
            events: {}
        },
        init: function () {
            Control.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            this.attachLiveChange(this.onLiveChange);
        },
        renderer: function (oRM, oControl) {
            sap.m.InputRenderer.render(oRM, oControl);
        },
        onLiveChange: function (e) {
            var _oInput = e.getSource();
            var val = _oInput.getValue();
            val = val.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
            _oInput.setValue(val);
        }
    });
});


// Small model
const model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  MyNumber: "10000000000000000000",
});

// Create an example of the control (JS not XML but idea is the same)
const input = new sample.control.NumericInput({
  valueState: "Error",
  valueStateText:"My Number must not be empty. Maximum 10 characters.",
  value: {
    path:'/MyNumber',
    type:'sap.ui.model.type.String',
    constraints:{minLength:1,maxLength:10}
  }
});

input.setModel(model);
input.placeAt('content');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script 
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3" 
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact">
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can greatly reduce your code to

```js
  Input.extend('NumericInput', {
    renderer: {
    },
    onAfterRendering: function () {
      if (Input.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
        Input.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      this.$().find("INPUT").each(function(i, input) {
        $(input).on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
         });
      });
    },
  });
```

https://jsbin.com/muberid/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Not sure introducing jquery is "greatly reducing code"

Comment: Yes, good idea. By the way SAPUI5 has jQuery as base so I don't mind using jQuery. I copied the code frame from samples with assumption that this might be the best practice.  However this doesn't answer my question about valueStateText missing.

Comment: It will be clear if you have a smaller code. There will be problem if you have too much code that are not required in your custom control. Thanks